# When does the tabId of a tab in Google Chrome change?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i am using onUpdate event listener but getting different tabId before and after loading has been done:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab){
    var i=ta.length;
    ta[i]=new Array(5);

    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tid, changeInfo, tabO){
        console.log(tid + " " + changeInfo.status);
        console.log(tab.id + " " + tabO.title); //tab.id is form onCreated event

        if( tid == tab.id && changeInfo.status === "complete" && tabO.title !== "New Tab") {
            console.log(tabO.title+"******"+tabO.url);//then do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

console.log

```
>200 loading script_new.js:12
>200 stackoverflow.com/questions/ask script_new.js:13
>200 undefined script_new.js:12
>194 stackoverflow.com/questions/ask script_new.js:13
>200 undefined script_new.js:12
>198 stackoverflow.com/questions/ask script_new.js:13
>200 undefined script_new.js:12
>200 stackoverflow.com/questions/ask script_new.js:13
>200 complete script_new.js:12
>194 Ask a Question - Stack Overflow
```

Comment: Both `addListener` statements are missing closing brackets and semicolons. BTW, why would you want to register an update listener within the created listener?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: the `tabId` of a Chrome tab doesn't change, although if you close a tab and use ctrl+shift+t to "reopen" it, it will be a new tab with a different ID.

As @DraškoKokić implied, each `onUpdated` handler will get called for every tab update, not just the tab whose `onCreated` handler you registered it inside, so you're getting somewhat misleading `console.log` output.